# send_from_directory with dynamic path

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use send_from_directory to return a file.This code works fine.

```
@app.route("/img/<filename>")
@login_required
def send_img(filename):
    path = '../py/img_detected/invador'
    return send_from_directory(path,filename)
```

But if I change the path to a dynamic path just like

```
@app.route("/img/<dir><filename>")
@login_required
def send_img(dir,filename):
    path = '../py/img_detected/%s'%dir
    return send_from_directory(path,filename)
```

It cannot work. Furthermore, I tried to change the `path = '../py/img_detected/invador'` to

```
dir='invador'
path = '../py/img_detected/%s'%dir
```

It cannot work either.
Can anyone tell me the reason of this problem? And what can I do if I want this function to be more flexible?

the error message is :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2017 04:56:41] "GET /invador_img HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Apr/2017 04:56:41] "GET /img/invador2017-04-07-01-37.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: "it cannot work" = what happens? What error do you get? Does `dir` include a path separator at the end? Perhaps `os.path.join(dir, filename)` would work.

Comment: It didn't return anything and throw any exception so I thought it cannot find the file. Your solution is great, thanks for your help.

Comment: You should post the error message as well

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I added the error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my mistake, I check the code again and find I miss '/' in `/<dir><filename>` which should be `/<dir>/<filename>` . And to edit the path, the code should be `os.path.join(dir, filename)` .